# Is there any way to make an Ember service available to all routes, controllers and components?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember 2.3.0 application and a service called `ui.js`. I constantly use this service across many routes, controllers and components. I normally inject the service manually into each route, controller and component by doing this:

```
ui: Ember.inject.service()
```

However, it's becoming very tedious to keep injecting it manually. How do I automatically make the UI service available to all routes, controllers and components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [initializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/initializers/#toc_application-initializers) to achieve this, create `app/initiliazers/ui.js`:

```
export default {
  name: 'ui',
  initialize(container, app) {
    app.inject('route', 'ui', 'service:ui');
    app.inject('controller', 'ui', 'service:ui');
    app.inject('component', 'ui', 'service:ui');
  }
};
```